# Swift 3 Dismissing from Struct after UIAlert

Tags: swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

still new to Swift and trying to get around few issues i keep facing now and then... :)
Now i have created a Struct to manage the user login, sign up and recover passowrd...

So here's the part of the code is driving me crazy...

```
struct NetworkingService {

var dataBaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference!{
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}
var storageRef: FIRStorageReference {
    return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
}
--------------------------------------------
// Reset Password
 func resetpassword(email: String){
    FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email, completion: { (error) in
        if error == nil{
            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "SUCCESS!", message: "We have sent an email to \(email) with the information on how to reset your password. Thank you!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

            })
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else{
            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Error:\(error!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

            })
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

and in my controller i have a simple button which call this func

```
ResetPasswordVC{
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

var networkingService = NetworkingService()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
 @IBAction func resetPasswordPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    networkingService.resetpassword(email: emailTextField.text!)
}
```

What I am trying to do is to dismiss the view and go back to previous viewController once the user has successfully resetted the password (basically if there are no errors and he has clicked ok on the alert.

Issue: cannot use dismiss in the struct. I have tried multiple solution but none of them have worked....
have tried this:

```
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
```

but i cannot use any animation (so the effect is really ugly) and the real problem is that LoginVC is a tabbed view and when i get back like this the bottom tabbed bar is just not displayed...
I have lost almost an entire day on it... and i really don't know what else to try...
Hope someone can help me!
P.S. if i have written some stupid things... please forgive me... like i said i'm a newbie... :D

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem before, what you need to do is show the Tabbar controller and set the tab of it properly instead of showing just the LoginVC otherwise like you found, the tabbar at the bottom will disappear

Comment: Thx for the answer... but like that i still get no animation... is there a way to add it?

Comment: unfortunately, AFAIK not directly. What I might suggest is having a a pop up that is just a loading wheel and then removing it once its done switching views. However, there's many other ways to show an animation (Y).

Comment: And if i do so... it shows the first tab... I am trying to show back the login which is my third tab (first two are just some table with news)

Comment: not a problem, you can do tabbar.selectedIndex = 2 (or whichever index it is, starts from 0) where tabbar is your UITabBarController.

Comment: Amazing! it worked... didn't know about it! thx! now i will figure how to add the animation and it's perfect! :) Thx!